# ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelField' from 'pydantic.fields'

Tags: python, pydantic, huggingface

I clone [this huggingface](https://huggingface.co/spaces/os1187/docquery) and tested on my app. But, I got this error.

```
===== Application Startup at 2023-11-12 13:13:59 =====

The cache for model files in Transformers v4.22.0 has been updated. Migrating your old cache. This is a one-time only operation. You can interrupt this and resume the migration later on by calling `transformers.utils.move_cache()`.
Moving 0 files to the new cache system
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
image-classification is already registered. Overwriting pipeline for task image-classification...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/app/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from docquery.document import load_document, ImageDocument
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docquery/document.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .ocr_reader import NoOCRReaderFound, OCRReader, get_ocr_reader
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docquery/ocr_reader.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pydantic.fields import ModelField
ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelField' from 'pydantic.fields' (/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/fields.py)
```

In my requirements.txt, I import like this. But it is not okay.

```
torch
git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git@21f6f58721dd9154357576be6de54eefef1f1818
git+https://github.com/impira/docquery.git@a494fe5af452d20011da75637aa82d246a869fa0#egg=docquery[web,donut]
```

I also tested with `pydantic==1.3` and it is not okay also. Can someone advise me please?

*Updated*: I have attached error log from my app in huggingface.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/impira/docquery/issues/68

Comment: I have used pydantic==1.10 but I am still having the error. How can I directly edit in the library for my app in huggingface? 

https://huggingface.co/spaces/kenneth984/transcript_automation/

Answer (score 2):

check the [migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/)

> field: this argument used to be a ModelField object, which was a
> quasi-internal class that no longer exists in Pydantic V2. Most of
> this information can still be accessed by using the field name from
> info.field_name to index into cls.model_fields

Comment: Thanks Yilmaz. I cannot directly edit here, File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docquery/ocr_reader.py" since it is from library. I can only modify app.py and requirements.txt.

Comment: https://huggingface.co/spaces/kenneth984/transcript_automation/